# a*b ≠ b*a? recursive function in C

Tags: c

input: `15 4` output: `1260`

```c
int recursive_combination(int n,int r){
    if(r==0) return 1;
    return (n-r+1)/r*recursive_combination(n,r-1);
}
```

input：`15 4` output `1365`

```c
int recursive_combination(int n,int r){
    if(r==0) return 1;
    return recursive_combination(n,r-1)*(n-r+1)/r;
}
```

why? I tried to make `n-r+1` in the first function to `n-r+1.0` and the result becomes `1362`(still not the correct answer).

Comment: This is the kind of problem where writing out the steps on paper or something would really help you understand what's going on. That, or stepping through the code line-by-line via a debugger.

Comment: Integer division does not respect `a / b * c = a * c / b`, because it is truncating fractional result. And depending on when it happens it would truncate it differently.

Comment: Integer division truncates any fractional result.

Comment: `a / b * c = a * c / b` doesn't even work most of the time in floating-point, since the precision is still finite

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, the `*` and `/` operators have equal precedence, so:

- `a / b * c` is equivalent to `(a / b) * c`, but
- `c * a / b` is equivalent to `(c * a) / b`.

(So the results you are getting from your code do not imply that a*b ≠ b*a in C.)

I don't understand what kind of problem you are solving here, but in general, if you are trying to calculate the product of a bunch of integers divided by the product of a bunch of integers, it is better to do the division operations at the end (if you can do so without overflows), so that the rounding error introduced by each division is less.  In other words, as long as `c * a / b` does not overflow, it could be more accurate than `a / b * c`.

Comment: Thanks for helping and your generous advice!